# Cannot maintain image aspect ratio/quality in android application

Tags: android

As the title suggest, I am having a lot of issues maintaining the quality and aspect ratio of my images on my android application.

Basically I have an image view and I am trying to get images to fit the image view and maintain it's image quality. I cant use fitxy because that will stretch the image to fill the entire imageview, but I only desire the image to automatically scale it's self and show as crisp as possible like your phone gallery.

In my code, I use fitCenter as the scale type and the size of the image seems alright, however the image is terrible distorted. This is the code.

Ive also included a snapshot of the android and iphone version to show how the exact same image is showing differently on the same image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- This controls layout for the slider in Gallery -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pagerimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATYCu.jpg)

[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pWKx.jpg)

```
public void handleGalleryImages() {

    try {
        for (int j = 0; j < imagesNaturalItemlist.size(); j++) {

            Log.e("ImagePATH>>>>>", imagesNaturalItemlist.get(j).getImage());
            String imageid = imagesNaturalItemlist.get(j).getUniqueId();
            downgalleryimage = new DownloadImage(imagesNaturalItemlist.get(j).getImage(), imageid);
            downgallerylist.add(downgalleryimage);
            beachimages.add(imagesNaturalItemlist.get(j).getImage());
        }

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

adapter

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sliding_pager_row, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pagerimage);

    if (images.get(position) != null && !images.get(position).equals("")) {
        //Picasso.with(context).load(images.get(position)).into(imageView);

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(images.get(position))
                .apply(new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).override(600, 250))
                .into(imageView);
    }

    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image you are attempting to display? It could be you are either scaling it down to much to be displayed in such a large area of the screen OR the original image is not high enough quality to begin with. Alternatively you can try setting a width and height for the image view and seeing if that resolves the blur issue.

Comment: @Devsil I don't think it's the image because see how crisp it is on the iPhone. Also, im wary of setting a width and height because I don' t want it to look good on some phones and terrible on others. It is a large image being scaled down but ( and correct me if im wrong) but isn't the scale type supposed to scale it down to fit as much as possible and only show what it can without the image quality being affected?

Because if I open, say "Interfacelift.com" on my phone, the images are full size on my laptop, but scaled for my phone

Comment: You are correct with how FitCenter ScaleType works but it depends on how you are placing the image in the image view exactly. Are you giving it a file path to where to find the image? or are you loading a scaled version of the bitmap into memory and placing it in your ImageView? If its the latter, ensure that you are not setting the scaleSize to small on the BitmapFactory.Options

Comment: @Devsil let me look at that and get back. Thanks

Comment: @Devsil  // .override(600, 250)) this was the issue in the glide